# Create large message draft

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have managed direct creation/send of message with smaller attachments. Then, for larger attachments I have managed the way, when the the draft message is created, and the attachments are sent separately to this draft as simple one-call-per-attachment or by creation of upload sessions. All this works fine.
But now I'm facing the problem, where the message BODY is larger than the 3 MB limit for the "packet/query" size. And I'm unable to find, how to set the draft message body over this limit.
Any advice?

Just to note, I'm doing this in PHP with the use of composer microsoft/microsoft-graph library, and some call with plain cURL (the upload sessions).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is impossible.
It seems like there is a 4Mb limit to the body for all Graph requests, including post message requests :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http